# HAPROXY ACL for same context different host

Tags: haproxy

I am having two URL as follows.

```
https://xyz.test.com/abc
and 
https://xyz-a.test.com/abc
```

For which I defined haproxy ACL as:-

```
acl is_1 path_beg /abc
use_backend server_1 if is_1

acl is_2 hdr(host) -i xyz-a.test.com
use_backend server_2 if is_2
```

However it is always ending on server 1. even if I try to browse it via URL

```
https://xyz-a.test.com/abc
```

Kindly suggest how I can handle above case.

I could use acl as below, to solve it:-

```
acl is_1 hdr(host) -i xyz.test.com
use_backend server_1 if is_1

acl is_2 hdr(host) -i xyz-a.test.com
use_backend server_2 if is_2
```

However I would like to keep the first acl as:-

```
acl is_1 path_beg /abc
use_backend server_1 if is_1
```

Any suggestions !!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about configuring haproxy.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple different ways to solve this. Here's the easiest one: just reverse the order of your use_backend statements!

```
acl is_1 path_beg /abc
acl is_2 hdr(host) -i xyz-a.test.com

use_backend server_2 if is_2
use_backend server_1 if is_1
```

The other way is to use an AND condition, which admittedly looks a little weird in HAproxy (you just append the ACL you want to AND with, potentially with modifiers):

```
acl is_1 path_beg /abc
acl is_2 hdr(host) -i xyz-a.test.com

use_backend server_1 if is_1 !is_2
use_backend server_2 if is_2
```

Comment: Considering the first solution you provided , is position of use backend matters in haproxy ? 

how does the things actually working behind so that change in position made it work ?

Comment: Just like an imperative computer program, the statements are evaluated in order. The first use_backend statement that matches its condition will fire. Otherwise, it will use the default_backend.

Answer (score 0):

The point is you have to use longer `acl` phrase in first line and then add the shorter one next line.

cause haproxy checks line by line.